# AssertionError on Olap4j with SSAS 2012

Tags: java, ssas, olap, olap4j

We are trying to run a OLAP query with olap4j against SSAS. I've managed to setup the XML/A endpoint, and SSMS connects to the endpoint correctly and works fine.

However each time I try to run a query from JAVA it fails.

```
Class.forName("org.olap4j.driver.xmla.XmlaOlap4jDriver");

Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
          "jdbc:xmla:Server=http://servername/msmdpump.dll;Catalog=DatabaseName");
OlapWrapper wrapper = (OlapWrapper) connection;
OlapConnection olapConnection = wrapper.unwrap(OlapConnection.class);

CellSet set = olapConnection.createStatement().executeOlapQuery(
        "SELECT [Measures].[Foo] ON COLUMNS, " +
        "[Dimension].[Id].[All].children ON ROWS FROM [Cube]");
```

The exception/stacktrace:

```
java.lang.AssertionError
    at org.olap4j.driver.xmla.XmlaOlap4jElement.<init>(XmlaOlap4jElement.java:43)
    at org.olap4j.driver.xmla.XmlaOlap4jProperty.<init>(XmlaOlap4jProperty.java:54)
    at org.olap4j.driver.xmla.XmlaOlap4jConnection$PropertyHandler.handle(XmlaOlap4jConnection.java:1890)
    at org.olap4j.driver.xmla.XmlaOlap4jConnection.populateList(XmlaOlap4jConnection.java:854)
    at org.olap4j.driver.xmla.DeferredNamedListImpl.populateList(DeferredNamedListImpl.java:136)
    at org.olap4j.driver.xmla.DeferredNamedListImpl.getList(DeferredNamedListImpl.java:90)
    at org.olap4j.driver.xmla.DeferredNamedListImpl.size(DeferredNamedListImpl.java:116)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.toArray(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.addAll(Unknown Source)
    at org.olap4j.driver.xmla.XmlaOlap4jLevel.getProperties(XmlaOlap4jLevel.java:189)
    at org.olap4j.driver.xmla.XmlaOlap4jConnection$MemberHandler.addUserDefinedDimensionProperties(XmlaOlap4jConnection.java:1739)
    at org.olap4j.driver.xmla.XmlaOlap4jConnection$MemberHandler.handle(XmlaOlap4jConnection.java:1698)
    at org.olap4j.driver.xmla.XmlaOlap4jConnection.populateList(XmlaOlap4jConnection.java:854)
    at org.olap4j.driver.xmla.XmlaOlap4jCube$RawMetadataReader.lookupMemberRelatives(XmlaOlap4jCube.java:547)
    at org.olap4j.driver.xmla.XmlaOlap4jCube$RawMetadataReader.lookupMemberByUniqueName(XmlaOlap4jCube.java:438)
    at org.olap4j.driver.xmla.XmlaOlap4jCube$DelegatingMetadataReader.lookupMemberByUniqueName(XmlaOlap4jCube.java:252)
    at org.olap4j.driver.xmla.XmlaOlap4jCube$CachingMetadataReader.lookupMemberByUniqueName(XmlaOlap4jCube.java:338)
    at org.olap4j.driver.xmla.XmlaOlap4jConnection$MeasureHandler.handle(XmlaOlap4jConnection.java:1555)
    at org.olap4j.driver.xmla.XmlaOlap4jConnection.populateList(XmlaOlap4jConnection.java:854)
    at org.olap4j.driver.xmla.XmlaOlap4jCube.<init>(XmlaOlap4jCube.java:110)
    at org.olap4j.driver.xmla.XmlaOlap4jConnection$CubeHandler.handle(XmlaOlap4jConnection.java:1284)
    at org.olap4j.driver.xmla.XmlaOlap4jConnection.populateList(XmlaOlap4jConnection.java:854)
    at org.olap4j.driver.xmla.DeferredNamedListImpl.populateList(DeferredNamedListImpl.java:136)
    at org.olap4j.driver.xmla.DeferredNamedListImpl.getList(DeferredNamedListImpl.java:90)
    at org.olap4j.driver.xmla.DeferredNamedListImpl.size(DeferredNamedListImpl.java:116)
    at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.hasNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.olap4j.driver.xmla.XmlaOlap4jCellSet.lookupCube(XmlaOlap4jCellSet.java:520)
    at org.olap4j.driver.xmla.XmlaOlap4jCellSet.createMetaData(XmlaOlap4jCellSet.java:403)
    at org.olap4j.driver.xmla.XmlaOlap4jCellSet.populate(XmlaOlap4jCellSet.java:181)
    at org.olap4j.driver.xmla.XmlaOlap4jStatement.executeOlapQuery(XmlaOlap4jStatement.java:372)
    at com.socgen.moma.services.pricingassetscope.DefaultPricingAssetScopeManagerTest.testOlap4j(DefaultPricingAssetScopeManagerTest.java:184)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:78)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:212)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
    14:17
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, the code tries to build an XMLA element with a null unique name.

```
XmlaOlap4jElement(
    String uniqueName,
    String name,
    String caption,
    String description)
{
    assert uniqueName != null;
```

Try sniffing the messages coming out of SSAS. There's probably something funky with the XML it returns.

Alternatively, you can take the high road and turn off assertions, but this error is a sign that something terribly wrong is going on and I recommend against this approach.

Comment: Found the issue. It is calculated measures. I can't believe it doesn't support calculated measures....

Comment: Although I've "found" that the issue is that it is trying to parse an `Expression` property, which has no `Description` (naturally), I have no idea what to do. It seems like a pretty major bug in olap4j.

Comment: Do calculated measures come out of SSAS without a unique name? Can you share a snippet of the XMLA response? As a workaround, you could disable assertions, but this has a JVM-wide effect.

Comment: Company policy would prevent me from doing so, and yes, calculated measures come out of SSAS without a null description I think (was pretty long time ago).